# How to access a subcolumn in JSON file in Pandas/Spark

Tags: json, pyspark

I have a JSON file and I want to access the "country" column

What I have done so far is resumed in this image:

[image]

Comment: please elaborate "Access" ?

Comment: Hi! Can you [please read](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557) about the problems with images of text and then edit your question to add transcriptions of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1):

See if below steps are useful -

1. Create a temp view on top of your dataframe.

```
df_sql.createOrReplaceTempView("SampleView")
```

2. Use spark sql to access 'Country' element like below -

```
df_country = spark.sql("select place:`country` from SampleView")
```

(This solution is as per your image)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by creating a new column in your dataframe like this:

```
df_sql.withColumn("country", F.col("place").getItem("country"))
```

The column country should contain the value of the key country in the column place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A question ¿What is 'F' ?

Comment: It is an import statement. 
from pyspark.sql import functions as F